# Confusion on newline and space match in R

Tags: r, newline, gsub

I am confused with the code below and hope someone can give me insight, in which it seems that **new line** can be matched by **space** in `gsub` in R.

Briefly, I used sprintf to prepare the SQL query statement, and to make the code readable and easy to modify, I splited the statement to mutliple lines. 
gsub was used to get rid of the newline characters, however to my surprise, it seems `\\s+` can match both new line and extra spaces.

```
chr = 1
pos = 1002
ref = 'A'
alt = 'G'

cmd <- sprintf("select * from MyDB 
              where `chr` ='%s'
              and pos = %i 
              and ref = %s 
              and alt = %s", 
              chr, pos, ref, alt)


cmd # where new lines were evident 

query <- gsub(pattern='\\n+',replacement=" ", cmd)
query #no new line, extra spaces remaining

query2 <- gsub(pattern='\\s+',replacement=" ", cmd)
query2 #new line and extra spaces all gone

query3 <- gsub(pattern="[[:space:]]+",replacement=" ", cmd)
query3 #same as query2
```

The code was tested in R version 3.5.1. Hope you can check the code and share your thoughts.

Comment: Thanks, MrFlick. I got the idea, thought \s just match the literal space(s).

Comment: @MrFlick that was an answer add it for your +1s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\s` is a white space character not just a literal space. see http://regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html.

And the `[[:space]]` character class is documented in R at ?regex to indicate: "Space characters: tab, newline, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, space and possibly other locale-dependent characters."

It would be somewhat odd to make up a whole class just for one character. You can use literal spaces " " in regular expressions.